# How to map value from xml to XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to populate data from xml to xslt n unable to do that since I do not have idea about xslt and xpath.Even though I tried my level best ( used concat() method ) but could not. could you please help me with below mapping?  :----

Xml:----(a piece of code)

```
<supportingProductFeatures>
    <type>NH</type>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <capacityAvailability>
      <featureType>TY1</featureType>
      <capacity>2</capacity>
      <unitOfMeasure>Mbps</unitOfMeasure>
      <highSpeedNotLessThan>true</highSpeedNotLessThan>
    </capacityAvailability>
  </supportingProductFeatures>
```

trying to achieve below one:--

```
<DescribedBy>
  <value>Yes</value> 
  <Characteristic>
    <name>NH TY1 High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to 2Mbps)</name> 
    <type>abcd</type>
  </Characteristic>
</DescribedBy>
```

condition to map:---

```
         if ((highSpeedNotLessThan!=null))
    {
            if(highSpeedNotLessThan.equals("true"){
            
            1) set value=yes
            2) set name=concat(type +" "+featureType+" "+"High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to 
              "+capacity+unitOfMeasure+")"
            3)  set type="abcd"
      }
            else if(highSpeedNotLessThan.equals("false"){
            
            1)set value=no
            2) set name=concat(type +" "+featureType+" "+"High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to 
              "+capacity+unitOfMeasure+")"
            3)  set type="abcd"
            }
}
```

this is what i have tried so far:--

```
<DescribedBy>
<xsl:if test="/supportingProductFeatures/capacityAvailability/highSpeedNotLessThan='true'">
<value>yes</value>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/supportingProductFeatures/capacityAvailability/highSpeedNotLessThan='false'">
<value>No</value>
</xsl:if>
<Characteristic>
    <name>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(supportingProductFeatures/type,' ',supportingProductFeatures/capacityAvailability/featureType,' ','High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to ',supportingProductFeatures/capacityAvailability/capacity,supportingProductFeatures/capacityAvailability/unitOfMeasure)" />
</name> 
    <type>abcd</type>
  </Characteristic>

 </DescribedBy>
```

Comment: If you have no idea about XSLT and XPath then you should learn about that and do some tutorials. And what exactly do you mean by "from XML to XSLT"? And what kind of language is this in your code snippet? It's neither Java nor XSLT. Please try to make it clear what your actual problem is. Your question is very confusing.

Comment: @vanje tried a lot using concat () method but did not work. so asking help

Comment: Yes, you already mentioned that. But that doesn't make things any clearer. You didn't respond to my questions at all. Maybe you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now it's completely unclear what you're even trying to accomplish.

Comment: @priyranjan so then please post your failed XSLT instead of some incomprehensible pseudocode!

Comment: @Gyro Gearless..what i have tried so far , added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it using XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Output>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//supportingProductFeatures"/>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="supportingProductFeatures">
    <DescribedBy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="capacityAvailability/highSpeedNotLessThan='true'">
          <value>Yes</value>
          <Characteristic>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="concat(type,' ',capacityAvailability/featureType,' ','High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to ',capacityAvailability/capacity,capacityAvailability/unitOfMeasure,')')"/></name>
          </Characteristic>
          <Type>abcd</Type>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="capacityAvailability/highSpeedNotLessThan='false'">
          <value>No</value>
          <Characteristic>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="concat(type,' ',capacityAvailability/featureType,' ','High Speed Tiers (greater or equal to ',capacityAvailability/capacity,capacityAvailability/unitOfMeasure,')')"/></name>
          </Characteristic>
          <Type>abcd</Type>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </DescribedBy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVrz

Note that since Characteristic and Type in your output are the same for the True and False cases you could take them out of the when conditions and have them for both cases, but I did it the same way your pseudocode is written.